# Calculation of response time in operating system

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

This was an exam question I could not solve, even after searching about response time.

I thought that answer should be `220, 120`

> Effectiveness of RR scheduling depends on two factors: choice of q, the time quantum, and the scheduling overhead s. If a system contains n processes and each request by a process consumes exactly q seconds, the response time (rt) for a request is rt= n(q+s) . This means that response is generated after spending the whole CPU burst and being scheduled to the next process. (after q+s)
>
> Assume that an OS contains 10 identical processes that were initiated at the same time. Each process contains 15 identical requests, and each request consumes 20msec of CPU time. A request is followed by an I/O operation that consumes 10 sec. The system consumses 2msec in CPU scheduling. Calculate the average reponse time of the fisrt requests issued by each process for the following two cases:
>
> - (i) the time quantum is 20msec.
> - (ii) the time quantum is 10 msec.

Comment: Should you assume that performing I/O blocks all other threads, or that it can happen in parallel with a task that is run on CPU? Also, did you notice that the I/O operation consumes 10 seconds (not milliseconds)?

Comment: Also, presumably this is a single-processor system?

Answer (score 0):

Note that I'm assuming you meant `10ms` instead of `10s` for the I/O wait time, and that nothing can run on-CPU while an I/O is in progress. In real operating systems, the latter assumption is not true.

Each process should take time `15 requests * (20ms CPU + 10ms I/O)/request = 450ms`.

Then, divide by the time quantum to get the number of scheduling delays, and add that to `450ms`:

1. `450ms / 20ms = 22.5` but actually it should be `23` because you can't get a partial reschedule. This gives the answer `450ms + 2ms/reschedule * 23 reschedules = 496ms`.
2. `450ms / 10ms = 45`. This gives the answer `450ms + 2ms/reschedule * 45 reschedules = 540ms`.